# XUbuntu: Open file browser via "run command" menu

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

In older Xubuntu versions, if I entered a path to a directory in the "run command" dialog, a thunar-window was opened showing this directory. I found that to be very handy if I would open f.e.g "/tmp", I just needed to press WindowsKey+r, enter /tmp and press enter, there I was. This was also great for URLs (ftp, http etc)

Unfortunately, since 12.04, this doesn't work anymore. It seem as if the "run command" is now integrated with the program finder. It still works when I type "thunar ftp://...." or "thunar /tmp", but it's a bit tedious now. Is there a way to restore the old behavior?

Note: I'm running a german localization of Xubuntu - I hope I translated "run command" and "program finder" correctly...

[image: run dialog]

Comment: This works for me in 12.04, but I am using Alt+F2 instead of the windows key. Do you get an error message, or prompted for a default application to use?

Comment: @maggotbrain Thanks for helping! I just had a look on my keyboard shortcut settings. <super>r Is associated with "/usr/bin/xfrun4", which is a symlink to xfce4-appfinder. Could you check with which program your Alt+F2 is associated?

Comment: Alt+F2 is set up to use xfrun4 for me

Comment: Same as mine. And you are sure that you can open e.g. and ftp location via the dialog?

Comment: Yes. I just confirmed that I can bring up local filesystems as well as the password prompt for ftp.mozilla.org

Comment: @maggotbrain I've just tested with a fresh user to make sure I didn't mess with the settings - same behavior. I've attached a screenshot that shows what the dialog looks like on my machine (sorry for this beeing german). Can you check if your "/usr/bin/xfrun4" is a symlink to the app-finder? In the meantime, I found out that thunar opens correctly when I enter "file:///tmp", but that is kind of tedious. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: Kein Problem. /usr/bin/xfrun4 is a direct link for me. No symlinks there. I don't have a good suggestion for resetting this behavior for you. I am running 12.04. Thunar 1.2.3. xfce4.8. Sorry.

Comment: @maggotbrain It seems that we're using different versions, since xfrun4 seems in deed to be replaced by the appfinder: http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6854   

Thanks for pointing me in this direction. Unfortunately, I cannot "accept" your comments to give you repu.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just make a shell script to run thunar and drop it in /usr/bin name thuna.

Have it run "thunar /tmp" if there is no argument specified.

So much easier than fighting with the launcher.